# Exclude a node field from loading

Tags: entities, nodes

I would like to exclude some of node field from loading while viewing nodes. 
I can hide fields currently, but I want to exclude it completly from loading. 
I have multivalued fields which have around 2000 records and I don't need to load it on node pages.

Answer (score 0):

On the 'manage display' page of your content type you can set fields as hidden. This will make the field not only hidden also it won't load it at all.

Comment: You're wrong. I know it will hide the field, but it will be loaded from the database. I checked it for my field collection fields.

Comment: Ok, ALL fields attached to a node will be available in the `$node` object. 'Manage display' is for managing the display, and the hidden fields will not be processed, even though they are available in the `$node` object. You may need to re-design your fields, using something like taxonomy to hold other values.

Comment: What do you mean? I though about some hook to alter the query or something like that.